# Grafico de burbujas gglop2 y packcircles

Tags: r, ggplot2

he armado el siguiente grafico de burbujas en R con ggplot2 y packcircles que adjunto. El problema es que las burbujas estan mal pintadas (aunque los colores estan bien), quiero que no aparezcan esas regiones triangulares por fuera y dentro de las burbujas, ni las lineas adicionales que unen las burbujas. Adicionalmente quisiera que las burbujas se vean mas redondeadas (y no con forma de elipse).

Muchas gracias por sus aportes.

[image: grafico]

a

```
library(packcircles)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)


df=data.frame(
 pais=c("Pais1","Pais1","Pais1", "Pais2","Pais2", "Pais2", "Pais3", "Pais3", "Pais4", "Pais4" , "Pais5", "Pais5"),
 estado=c("A1","A2",'A3',"B1","B2","B3","C1","C2",'D1','D2','E1','E2'),
 fob=c(1000,500,200, 700,300,500, 500,100, 300, 400,200,600)
)


df=df %>% ungroup() %>% arrange(pais, desc(fob)) %>% mutate(id=1:nrow(.))

p <- circleProgressiveLayout( df$fob )
d <- circleLayoutVertices(p)

p=p %>% mutate(id=1:nrow(.))

cols <- c("Pais1" = "#0eb2e7", "Pais2" = "#74c8e0", "Pais3" = "#a4d6e1", "Pais4" = "#ddeff1", "Pais5" = "#ddded9")
cols=cols[ sort( unique( df$pais)) ]

d=d %>% left_join( df, by='id' )
p=p %>% left_join( df, by='id' )

grafico= ggplot(  d, aes(x, y, colour = factor(pais, levels =names(cols), labels = names(cols) ),
              fill = factor(pais, levels =names(cols), labels = names(cols)  ))) +
  geom_polygon()+
  scale_colour_manual(
    values = cols,
    aesthetics = c("colour", "fill")
  ) +
  
  geom_text(data =p,  aes(x, y, label =estado),color='black')+
  theme_void()+
  
  theme(legend.position='bottom', legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text =element_text( size = 10, face = 'bold')) 

grafico
```

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas especificar la dimensión `group` para poder "independizar" cada circulo, sino todo es un mismo poligono:

```
aes(x, 
    y,
    colour = factor(pais, levels =names(cols), labels = names(cols)),
    fill = factor(pais, levels =names(cols), labels = names(cols)),
    group = id)
```

En tu caso, entiendo que `id` agrupa cada circulo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora si me quedaron bien pintadas las burbujas!.